# Alternative plot solution to a ggplot with legends for each panel?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I am trying to ggplot 8 environmental variables in a single plot. Because the range values of the variables are very different, only one graph displays variation. The solution is to have for each graph its own legend, which I do not seem able to do.
This is the code I am using for the ggplot:

```
p1 <- ggplot()+
  geom_raster(data=wide,mapping=aes(x,y,fill=climate_value))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=col)+
  scale_x_continuous(name=expression(paste("Longitude")),limits=c(long.min,long.max),expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_y_continuous(name=expression(paste("Latitude")),limits=c(lat.min,lat.max),expand=c(0,0))+
  coord_equal()

p2 <- p1 + theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
           panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
           panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
p3 <-p2 + facet_wrap(~climate_variable, nrow=2)
p3
```

I think this is not feasible with ggplot. Is there an alternative fot the same time of aesthetics but using other plotting functions?

Any help will be most appreciated, but please bear in mind I am not an R coder, I simply copy and adapt code!
Many thanks,
R

ggplot with only one legend, which is not what I want!
[image: ggplot with only one legend, which is not what I want!]

Comment: Can you edit your post and share your data? Add the output of `dput(wide)` to your question.

Comment: Check out `cowplot`. You can split your dataframe by `climate_variable` or whatever, map over the list to make a list of plots, and arrange them as separate plots on one screen/page using `cowplot`

Comment: `grob()` and `grid.arrange()` and `arrangeGrob()` in the grid and gridExtra packages are also excellent for combining ggplots into complex multipanel figures

Comment: Many thanks, I will look into your suggestions, and post the result.